# можно ли сделать функцию, импортируя условия из pygame, и потом засунуть эту функцию в if для сокращения кода?

Tags: python, pygame

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 1 and button_exit_x - indificator_button_exit_x <= place[0] <= button_exit_x + indificator_button_exit_x and button_exit_y - indificator_button_exit_y <= place[1] <= button_exit_y + indificator_button_exit_y :
            button_exit_x = 100
```

#и все это потом засунуть в функцию, для сокращения строки возможно?

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно использовать какую-то функцию, а написать все красивее:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if (event.button == 1 
        and abs(place[0] - button_exit_x) <= indificator_button_exit_x 
        and abs(place[1] - button_exit_y) <= indificator_button_exit_y):
        button_exit_x = 100
```

---

*Постепенное объяснение:*

Сначала ваше долгое условие поместим в скобки, чтобы длинную строку синтактически правильно разделить в несколько строк:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if (event.button == 1 
        and button_exit_x - indificator_button_exit_x <= place[0] <= button_exit_x + indificator_button_exit_x 
        and button_exit_y - indificator_button_exit_y <= place[1] <= button_exit_y + indificator_button_exit_y):
        button_exit_x = 100
```

Затем отчислим из всех трех стран первой длинной строки `button_exit_x`, и из второй `button_exit_y`:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if (event.button == 1 
        and -indificator_button_exit_x <= place[0] - button_exit_x <= +indificator_button_exit_x 
        and -indificator_button_exit_y <= place[1] - button_exit_y <= +indificator_button_exit_y):
        button_exit_x = 100
```

Видим, что среднее выражение должно находится между минус и плюс того же самого значения, и упрощаем обе длинные строки применением функции `abs()` (абсолютное значение):

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if (event.button == 1 
        and abs(place[0] - button_exit_x) <= indificator_button_exit_x 
        and abs(place[1] - button_exit_y) <= indificator_button_exit_y):
        button_exit_x = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def some_name(event, place, button_exit_x, button_exit_y, indificator_button_exit_x, indificator_button_exit_y):
    return event.button == 1 and button_exit_x - indificator_button_exit_x <= place[0] <= button_exit_x + indificator_button_exit_x and button_exit_y - indificator_button_exit_y <= place[1] <= button_exit_y + indificator_button_exit_y
```

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if some_name(event, place, button_exit_x, button_exit_y, indificator_button_exit_x, indificator_button_exit_y):
        button_exit_x = 100
```